# Exception in assembly move instruction?

Tags: assembly, nasm, rules, mov

I realize that it is forbidden to copy from memory to memory in scenarios like this:

```
section .data
var1 db 23
var2 db 9

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov [var1],[var2]
mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

But, recently I found code example that is not exactly following the rule.
Here is the idea:

```
section .data
var1 dd 23
var2 dd 9

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov dword [var1],var2
mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

I know we can't transport data between memory locations, but I wonder if is possible to pass memory location of one variable to another variable. 
It actually compiles, and does the job.
My question is: Is this really suppose to work?
Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure, you can store the address of `var2` in `var1`, as you do here, but that's a different operational outcome than in your first example.

Comment: `mov [var1],[var2]` would have been an attempt to copy the value of _var1_ into _var2_. Both operands are memory operands so you can't do that. `mov dword [var1],var2` moves the pointer for _var2_ into _var1_. A pointer is just an immediate value (like a constant) so this operation is permitted with _MOV_

Comment: Thank you, good explanation. :)

Comment: No problem. I did mean in the first case it was `copy the value of var2 into var1`. I wrote it backwards.

Comment: I can see that now. Too tired. Anyway, it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `var2` is being used as an actual memory address literal.  In other words, it is not trying to move something to or from that address, it is moving the value of the address into the `[var1]` location.

Comment: I see, it is like constant, like mentioned above. Thank you. :)